# How to vectorize code in Python for a heat dispersion problem?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, vectorization

I am trying to vectorize the following code below, but I do not know how to get started. The problem is the writing a piece of code given a numpy array. The 2D array contains elements which represent the temperature of steel on the front side profile. The outer ring of elements represents the temperature if a hot clamp is acting upon the steel. They remain constant, but the inner elements/ temperatures will change after t amount of seconds. The objective is to return the array at the time-step of 1. The equation describes what will happen to the elements after t seconds.

```
()=((−1)[+1,] + (−1) [−1,] +(−1)[,+1] + (−1)[,−1])/ 4
```

The brackets contain the location of the element. Anything is helpful. Thanks!

```
#u is the numpy array
arr = np.copy(u)
for i in range(len(u)):
    for j in range(len(u[i])):
        if i == 0 or i == (len(u) - 1) or j == 0 or j == (len(u[i]) - 1):
            continue
        else:
            arr[i][j] = (u[i + 1][j] + u[i - 1][j] + u[i][j + 1] + u[i][j - 1]) / 4
return arr
```

Ex:
For example, the array:

```
100   100   100   100   100  
100    0     0     0    100  
100    0     0     0    100  
100    0     0     0    100  
100   100   100   100   100
```

The array above returns the array:

```
100   100   100   100   100  
100    50    25    50   100   
100    25     0    25   100  
100    50    25    50   100  
100   100   100   100   100
```

after a time-step of 1

Answer (score 0):

Youre close, to change an element of a numpy array [numpy indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html) for assignment instead. This alone should fix your solution. (use `arr[i, j] =` instead of `arr[i][j] =`)
Another comment I would make of your code is the use of the [range function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range). You can simplify and increase readability by limiting the index of your array instead of checking its an index that is not allowed. See my example:

```
def timestep(arr):
    rval = np.copy(arr)

    for row in range(1, arr.shape[0] - 1):  # arr.shape returns (width, height)
        for col in range(1, arr.shape[1] - 1):
            rval[row, col] = (arr[row-1, col] + arr[row+1, col] + arr[row, col-1] + arr[row, col+1]) / 4
    return rval

print(arr)
print(timestep(arr))
```

this outputs

```
[[100 100 100 100 100]
 [100   0   0   0 100]
 [100   0   0   0 100]
 [100   0   0   0 100]
 [100 100 100 100 100]]
[[100 100 100 100 100]
 [100  50  25  50 100]
 [100  25   0  25 100]
 [100  50  25  50 100]
 [100 100 100 100 100]]
```

with your example.